# What causes super small numbers in javascript to be recognized as different booleans?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, math

Why do these very small numbers have different outputs?

[image: Chrome Javascript Console]

What is the decider on how small a number can be before it is no longer true and turns to false?

One number (top) is 327 characters long (324 zeros after decimal) has an output of `true`:
`0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

The other (bottom) is 326 characters long (323 zeros after decimal) has an output of `false`:
`0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

Upon further investigation:
[image]

Why would this make or break a number?

Comment: One of those is a small nonzero number, the other is just 0 (expressed in a longer than usual format), it's not broken, it's just closer to 0 than any other JavaScript number and JavaScript always uses the closest number .

Comment: take a look to [Number.MIN_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just run out of bits to represent your number.

Numbers in javascript are [IEEE 754 Double precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (type "double" in C). Doubles are encoded as follows:

```
 ┌─┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┐
 │ │ bits 52-62 │           bits 0 - 51                │
 └─┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘
  ^     ^                  ^
  │     │                  └── number (also called mantissa)
  │     └────── exponent
  └── sign bit
```

The formula for interpreting the encoding is:

```
            (exponent - 1023)
number x  2
```

Or in code it would look like:

```
number * Math.pow(2, exponent - 1023)
```

Therefore the smallest number that javascript (or C/Java/C# etc. doubles) can represent is:

```
1 x 2⁻¹⁰²²   // exponent 0 has special meaning so the smallest exponent is 1
```

This is actually `5 x 10⁻³²⁴`. Which is:

```
0.0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000
  0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000
  0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000
  0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000
  0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000
  0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000
  0000000000 0000000000 0005
```

Anything smaller cannot be represented and is therefore rounded to the nearest representable number.

Comment: Anything smaller than `Number.MIN_VALUE` but bigger than `Number.MIN_VALUE/2` is `Number.MIN_VALUE`. Anyhing smaller than or equal to `Number.MIN_VALUE/2` is zero.

Comment: @Paulpro Ah, yes. Forgot about rounding